# How can I dynamically edit gridview data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to edit and delete fields in a gridview, not connected with database and gridview is being populated with data entered by a user in the textboxes? Also, how can I remove the row using delete button in the gridview?

this is my grid view in ASP page :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid"
        ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Width="70%" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Code">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemCode") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="ItemCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemCode") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Product") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Product" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Product") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="UnitPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Batch">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBatch" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Batch") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Batch" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Batch") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField FooterText="Total" HeaderText="Expiary Date">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiaryDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExpiaryDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="ExpiaryDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExpiaryDate") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Quantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="GetQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# GetQuantity() %>'></asp:Label>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Total" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Total") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="GetTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# GetTotal() %>'></asp:Label>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" EditImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png"
                HeaderText="EDIT" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" ForeColor="Black" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" HorizontalAlign="Right" /> 
 </asp:GridView>
```

I'm using this code to add data to the grid.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
    {
        var dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
        var count = dt.Rows.Count;
        BindGrid(count);
    }
    else
    {
        BindGrid(1);
    }
    Clear();
}

private void BindGrid(int rowcount)
{
    var DataTbl = new DataTable();

    DataRow DataRw;

    DataTbl.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(String));
    DataTbl.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(String));
    DataTbl.Columns.Add("UnitPrice", typeof(String));
    DataTbl.Columns.Add("Batch", typeof(String));
    DataTbl.Columns.Add("ExpiaryDate", typeof(String));
    DataTbl.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(double));
    DataTbl.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(double));

    if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < rowcount + 1; i++)
        {
            DataTbl = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];

            if (DataTbl.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRw = DataTbl.NewRow();
                DataRw[0] = DataTbl.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            }
        }
        DataRw = DataTbl.NewRow();
        DataRw[0] = txtItemCode.Text;
        DataRw[1] = ddlProduct.SelectedItem;
        DataRw[2] = txtUnitPrice.Text;
        DataRw[3] = txtBatch.Text;
        DataRw[4] = txtExpiaryDate.Text;
        DataRw[5] = txtQty.Text;
        DataRw[6] = (Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(
            txtUnitPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(
                txtQty.Text)) - ((Convert.ToDouble(
                    txtUnitPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(
                        txtQty.Text))) * Convert.ToDouble(
                            txtProductDiscount.Text) / 100).ToString();
        DataTbl.Rows.Add(DataRw);
    }
    else
    {
        DataRw = DataTbl.NewRow();
        DataRw[0] = txtItemCode.Text;
        DataRw[1] = ddlProduct.SelectedItem;
        DataRw[2] = txtUnitPrice.Text;
        DataRw[3] = txtBatch.Text;
        DataRw[4] = txtExpiaryDate.Text;
        DataRw[5] = txtQty.Text;
        DataRw[6] = (Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(
            txtUnitPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(
                txtQty.Text)) - ((Convert.ToDouble(
                    txtUnitPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(
                        txtQty.Text))) * Convert.ToDouble(
                            txtProductDiscount.Text) / 100).ToString();
        DataTbl.Rows.Add(DataRw);
    }

    if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = DataTbl;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    ViewState["CurrentData"] = DataTbl;
}
```

Comment: how you are filling your grid...paste the code..

Comment: code added .. i need some help.. :)

Comment: U said that u r creating gridview dynamically,but the code is not...its static only..

Comment: i think i made a mistake .. I'm taking data from textboxes.. so how to edit remove fields in gridview

Comment: Just make clear,what is your requirement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your code and query is not clear.
if i am understanding it right then the problem in your code is that data is not deleting or updating.

as i saw in your code, you are holding data in view state. please recheck your code at the stage of `GridView1_RowUpdating()` and `GridView1_RowCommand()` (hoping you are using this for delete) events. after `deleting/updating` the data you should update the view state also.